# Android: Fragment And Activity Working Together

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

Following is the app flow

Activity => fragment

Fragment had some empty space. When clicking on the empty space of fragment, I'm accessing the functions of activity. How to get rid this?

Here's my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_send_email_top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="51dp"
        android:background="@color/top_layout" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_send_email_layout_back"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/empty"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_back" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_send_email_middle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rl_send_email_top"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_send_email_layout_desc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/send_email_layout_desc"
            android:textColor="@color/forgot"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_send_email_layout_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_send_email_layout_desc"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_radius_boarder"
            android:hint="@string/send_email_layout_email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_send_layout_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/et_send_email_layout_email"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_radius_boarder"
            android:hint="@string/send_email_layout_name"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_send_layout_phone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/et_send_layout_name"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_radius_boarder"
            android:hint="@string/send_email_layout_phone"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_send_layout_message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/et_send_layout_phone"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_radius_boarder"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:hint="@string/send_email_layout_message"
            android:inputType="textShortMessage|textAutoCorrect|textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
            android:maxLength="2000"
            android:maxLines="5"
            android:minLines="5"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_send_email_layout_submit"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/et_send_layout_message"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:background="@color/forgot"
            android:text="@string/send_email_layout_submit"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you please share your layout.xml file

Comment: Hi Neeraj Singh, please see the edited version

Comment: Kiran you have just paste fragment layout xml, I was asking for main layout where you merge this layout.

Answer (score 0):

Short question, short answer.

The fragment must be inside a holder.

Just make the holder Match_Parent.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi from the initial time also i'm using match_parent for holder but it's not working. Please see my edited version of my question (i included xml file)

Answer (score 0):

you can access activity public methods in fragment like below

```
((BaseActivity) getActivity()).replaceFragmentWithStack(new ReportFragment());
```

Place some code to it helps you more :-)

Comment: i think he wants to make his fragment NOT beeing able using activity-methods